# Javascript copy cell value in table

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JavaScript so wanted to ask a very simple basic question. I have HTML which is listed below:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CellOneRowOne</td>
      <td>CellTwoRowOne</td>
      <td>>>></td>
      <td>CellFourRowOne</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to write a JavaScript function so that when the user clicks on the arrows displayed in the cell 3 of the row, the value from the cell-1 row-1 get copied to cell-4 row-1.

Comment: Helpful resources: [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Comment: Please provide the JS you have attempted, even if it doesn't work at all. It's no use giving you code that you might not understand or code you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's both the JS and HTML codes.
Note that you can use that "copy_vals" function for any further row, provided that its input argument is equal to the same index of row including
the function call.

Being a newbie, you might like to be addressed to invent strategies working in any case (here, whatever the row index is), according to the current environment.

As you see, I wrote it once and I called it twice: the less effort, the more afford ! (as I like to say)

Happy coding !

```js
function copy_vals(_row_id) {
  var _src = document.getElementById("cell" + _row_id + "_1");
  var _dest = document.getElementById("cell" + _row_id + "_4");
  _dest.innerHTML = _src.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td ID="cell1_1">CellOneRowOne</td>
    <td ID="cell1_2">CellTwoRowOne</td>
    <td ONCLICK="javascript:copy_vals(1);">>>></td>
    <td ID="cell1_4">CellFourRowOne</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ID="cell2_1">CellOneRowTwo</td>
    <td ID="cell2_2">CellTwoRowTwo</td>
    <td ONCLICK="javascript:copy_vals(2);">>>></td>
    <td ID="cell2_4">CellFourRowTwo</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Just FYI, the `javascript:` label does nothing there, and you don't need to hard code the index numbers into the function calls. You can pass `this` instead, and after renaming the parameter to something like `elem`, you can get the row number with `elem.parentNode.rowIndex`.

Comment: @sqint, though the `javascript:` is the default, I've found that it's nice to include (for other maintainers that are not so technically savvy), but you're right, it's a vestige, not a necessity.

Comment: @vol7ron `javascript:` is not the default, because there is no other alternative than being parsed in JS. The contents of an `onclick` attribute are an internal raw uncompiled handler. This is not like a link, which expects an URI but you can use the `javascript:` scheme to run JS. Here `javascript:` is treated as a [label](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the 3 elements involved via JavaScript and then set up the cell to be clicked to be able to respond to being clicked by taking one cell value and placing it into another.

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script>
        var c1r1 = document.getElementById("c1r1");
        var cellToClick = document.getElementById("cellToClick");
        var c4r1 = document.getElementById("c4r1");

        cellToClick.addEventListener("click", function(){
           c4r1.innerHTML = c1r1.innerHTML;
        });
    </script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="c1r1">CellOneRowOne</td>
    <td>CellTwoRowOne</td>
    <td id="cellToClick">>>></td>
    <td id="c4r1">CellFourRowOne</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds an event to every arrow, which is not the most performant choice, but if your table/page is small, it shouldn't matter and is easier to manage the code.

```js
function copyCell(e)
{  
  var link = this,
      td = link.parentNode,
      tr = td.parentNode,
      cells = tr.children;
  
  cells[3].innerHTML = cells[0].innerHTML;
  
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3) :link');

for (var i=0,n=links.length; i<n; i++){
  var link = links[i];
  link.addEventListener('click', copyCell, false);
}
```

```css
td { text-align: center; }
td:nth-child(3) :link{ text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CellOneRowOne</td>
      <td>CellTwoRowOne</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;">&rarr;</span></td>
      <td>CellFourRowOne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;">&rarr;</span></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```